# symfony get parameter from virtualhost

Tags: symfony, parameters, virtualhost

- virtualhost :

  ```
  SetEnv SYMFONY_PEM /etc/ssl/certs/certif.pem
  ```

  and i restarted server
- services.yaml

  ```
  pem: '%env(SYMFONY_PEM)%'
  ```
- service :

  ```
  $pem = $params->get('pem');
  $this->client = new Client(['verify' => $pem, ]);
  ```

**Environment variable not found: "SYMFONY_PEM".**

help !

Comment: Can you specify your sf version ?

Comment: Try with quotes: `SetEnv SYMFONY_PEM "/etc/ssl/certs/certif.pem"`

Comment: with quotes he does'nt work !!!    and   Symfony 4.2